# Refatoração de função para remover pontuação, espaços e caracteres especiais

Tags: php, acentuação, sanitize, refatoração

Tenho esta função já muito antiga para "limpar" o conteúdo de uma variável:

#### Função

```php
function sanitizeString($string) {

    // matriz de entrada
    $what = array( 'ä','ã','à','á','â','ê','ë','è','é','ï','ì','í','ö','õ','ò','ó','ô','ü','ù','ú','û','À','Á','É','Í','Ó','Ú','ñ','Ñ','ç','Ç',' ','-','(',')',',',';',':','|','!','"','#','$','%','&','/','=','?','~','^','>','<','ª','º' );

    // matriz de saída
    $by   = array( 'a','a','a','a','a','e','e','e','e','i','i','i','o','o','o','o','o','u','u','u','u','A','A','E','I','O','U','n','n','c','C','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_' );

    // devolver a string
    return str_replace($what, $by, $string);
}
```

#### Utilização

```php
<?php
$pessoa = 'João dos Santos Videira';

$pastaPessoal = sanitizeString($pessoa);

// resultado
echo $pastaPessoal; // Joao_dos_Santos_Videira
?>
```

Sendo uma função antiga, na altura da sua criação fazer uma substituição de um caráter A por B era a melhor opção, mas fazer manutenção a uma matriz de entrada e uma matriz de saída não é fácil e de volta e meia lá aparece um cenário não previsto.

Com a evolução do PHP, como refatorar esta função fazendo uso de soluções da própria linguagem ou mais fáceis de manter?

Comment: Nota referente à tag **sanitize**: Não consegui traduzir ou encontrar uma tag já existente para esta palavra.

Comment: Marque uma resposta como aceita, se uma delas serve para você.

Comment: **sanitize** significa sanitizar ou higienizar. Mas é meio feio traduzir pra isso, rs! Deixa sanitize mesmo.

Answer (score 25):

Basta usar expressões regulares!

```php
<?php
function sanitizeString($str) {
    $str = preg_replace('/[áàãâä]/ui', 'a', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/[éèêë]/ui', 'e', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/[íìîï]/ui', 'i', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/[óòõôö]/ui', 'o', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/[úùûü]/ui', 'u', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/[ç]/ui', 'c', $str);
    // $str = preg_replace('/[,(),;:|!"#$%&/=?~^><ªº-]/', '_', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', '_', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/_+/', '_', $str); // ideia do Bacco :)
    return $str;
}
?>
```

A linha de código abaixo do comentário serve para substituir todos os caracteres  por "_", exceto se for letras ou números.

Comment: Se eu tivesse que implementar, faria algo parecido com essa resposta. Todavia, para um projeto em produção acho que usar a URLify (ver minha resposta) é mais vantagem no longo prazo, já que é bem testada, fácil de estender e modificar.

Answer (score 8):

Acho que essa seria a melhor e mais simples solução para seu problema:

```php
$valor = "João dos Santos Videira" 
$valor = str_replace(" ","_",preg_replace("/&([a-z])[a-z]+;/i", "$1", htmlentities(trim($valor))));
// Joao_dos_Santos_Videira
```

Caso queira manter os espaços em vez de trocá-los por "`_`", basta apenas retirar o `str_replace`:

```php
$valor = "João dos Santos Videira" 
$valor = preg_replace("/&([a-z])[a-z]+;/i", "$1", htmlentities(trim($valor)));
// Joao dos Santos Videira
```

Comment: Esta foi a melhor resposta e solução. Acrescentei duas coisas em meu sistema de login: `$FormataLogin = str_replace(" ","",strtolower(preg_replace("/&([a-z])[a-z]+;/i", "$1", htmlentities(trim($_POST['login'])))));` Obrigado.

Comment: Ótima resposta.

Answer (score 6):

Você pode querer usar a biblioteca [URLify.php](https://github.com/jbroadway/urlify) ([código fonte aqui](https://github.com/jbroadway/urlify/blob/master/URLify.php)), que possui testes extensivos para suportar diversos caracteres e idiomas, e também suporta adicionar mapeamentos mais complexos que *1 caractere -> 1 caractere*.

Ela também ignora símbolos que não consegue transliterar, o que a deixa bastante robusta para usar numa URL ou nome de arquivo.

Seguem alguns exemplos da página do projeto:

#### Limpando para usar em URL ou nome de arquivo

```
echo URLify::filter (' J\'étudie le français ');
// "jetudie-le-francais"    
echo URLify::filter ('Lo siento, no hablo español.');
// "lo-siento-no-hablo-espanol"
```

#### Apenas removendo os caracteres especiais por ASCII

```
echo URLify::downcode ('J\'étudie le français');
// "J'etudie le francais"
echo URLify::downcode ('Lo siento, no hablo español.');
// "Lo siento, no hablo espanol."
```

#### Mapeando caracteres complexos para expressões

```
URLify::add_chars (array (
    '¿' => '?', '®' => '(r)', '¼' => '1/4',
    '¼' => '1/2', '¾' => '3/4', '¶' => 'P'
));    
echo URLify::downcode ('¿ ® ¼ ¼ ¾ ¶');
// "? (r) 1/2 1/2 3/4 P"
```

Answer (score 6):

Pode usar o PHP para remover acentos de forma simples usando iconv, respeitando maiúsculas e minusculas sem conflito. `IGNORE` vai ignorar os caracteres que porventura não tenham tradução. Depois `preg_replace` vai remover o que não for `A-Z` e `0-9`, deixando uma string limpa sem espaços, símbolos ou caracteres especiais.

```
$string = "ÁÉÍÓÚáéíóú! äëïöü";
$string = iconv( "UTF-8" , "ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE" , $string );
$string = preg_replace( array( '/[ ]/' , '/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/' ) , array( '' , '' ) , $string );

-----------------------------------------------------------------
Input:  ÁÉÍÓÚáéíóú! äëïöü
Output: AEIOUaeiouaeiou
```

<sub>Veja um exemplo no [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/o1Dfr8)</sub>

Comment: Uma pequena alteração para quem precisa manter o espaço



```php
$string = "ÁÉÍÓÚáéíóú! äëïöü"; 
$string = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $string);
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/', '', $string);
-------------------
Input:  ÁÉÍÓÚáéíóú! äëïöü
Output: AEIOUaeiou aeiou
```

Answer (score 4):

Tu procura pela função [`strtr()`](http://www.php.net/strtr). As expressões regulares ajudam a tratar dos casos excepcionais:

```php
function sanitizeString($str)
{
    return preg_replace('{\W}', '', preg_replace('{ +}', '_', strtr(
        utf8_decode(html_entity_decode($str)),
        utf8_decode('ÀÁÃÂÉÊÍÓÕÔÚÜÇÑàáãâéêíóõôúüçñ'),
        'AAAAEEIOOOUUCNaaaaeeiooouucn')));
}
```

**PS:** Usei a função [`utf8_decode()`](http://www.php.net/utf8_decode) porque salvo os arquivos como UTF-8 em meu sistema (OSX). É provável que não precise usá-la caso o arquivo seja salvo em outras codificações como ISO-8859-1, CP1252 e afins.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas estou um pouco confuso após ler a mesma. Falas em `utf8_encode()` mas utilizas `utf8_decode()` na função. Por outra lado dizes que usas `utf8*` por causa da forma como guardas o ficheiro? Assumo que estejas a dizer isso porque os `headers` da aplicação não estão em `UFT-8`? Não tive oportunidade de testar a tua solução, mas se entretanto for possível clarificar estas minhas duvidas, agradeço!

Comment: Oops! Eu me referia à `utf8_decode()` mesmo, já corrigi  minha observação... No meu caso é necessário usar a `utf8_decode()` porque salvo os arquivos com a codificação UTF-8 em meu sistema... Isso se faz necessário justamente por causa dos caracteres acentuados que estão sendo usados na função.

Answer (score 0):

Eu desenvolvi uma forma diferente para remover todos os caracteres especiais e acentos.

```
<?php

$VString = "Matan-zá@Ç/_454ç8";

echo "Com caracteres especiais e acentos: " . $VString . "<br>";

$VString = preg_replace("/[ÁÀÂÃÄ]/", "A", $VString);
$VString = preg_replace("/[áàâãä]/", "a", $VString);
$VString = preg_replace("/[ÉÈÊ]/", "E", $VString);
$VString = preg_replace("/[éèê]/", "e", $VString);
$VString = preg_replace("/[ÍÌ]/", "I", $VString);
$VString = preg_replace("/[íì]/", "i", $VString);
$VString = preg_replace("/[ÓÒÔÕÖ]/", "O", $VString);
$VString = preg_replace("/[óòôõö]/", "o", $VString);
$VString = preg_replace("/[ÚÙÜ]/", "u", $VString);
$VString = preg_replace("/[úùü]/", "u", $VString);
$VString = preg_replace("/[Ç]/", "C", $VString);
$VString = preg_replace("/[ç]/", "c", $VString);
$VString = preg_replace("/[Ñ]/", "N", $VString);
$VString = preg_replace("/[ñ]/", "n", $VString);

echo "Com caracteres especiais: " . $VString . "<br>";

$VNovo = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($VString); $i++)
  if (preg_match ("/[a-zA-Z0-9]/", substr($VString, $i, 1)) == 1)
    $VNovo .= substr($VString, $i, 1);

echo "Sem caracteres especiais e acentos: " . $VNovo . "<br>";
```

Answer (score -1):

```php
public static function removerCaracteresEspeciaiss($str){
    $str_saida = "";
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($str); $i++){
        $num_asc = ord($str[$i]);
        if( ($num_asc>=65 && $num_asc<=90) || ($num_asc>=97 && $num_asc<=122) || ($num_asc>=48 && $num_asc<=57)){
            $str_saida .= $str[$i];
        }
    }
    return $str_saida;
}
```