# Como remover acento no upload com php?

Tags: php

Parte do arquivo está funcionando. O problema é que quando envio um arquivo com acento. Exemplo: envio um arquivo com o nome `ação-íaaa.jpg` ele fica assim no servidor `aÃ§Ã£o-Ã­aaa.jpg`. Então queria remover os acentos para ficar assim `acao-iaaa.jpg`. Sugestões?

```
$destination_path = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$result = 0;
$target_path = $destination_path . basename( $_FILES['myfile']['name']);
if(@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
$result = 1;}
sleep(1);
```

Comment: Como você já percebeu, é importante que o *encoding* da página e do PHP estejam setados corretamente (pois se o client enviar lixo, nada do que você fizer no server vai consertar). Uma vez feito isso, as soluções propostas devem funcionar corretamente.

Comment: [Nessa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/858/refatora%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-remover-pontua%C3%A7%C3%A3o-espa%C3%A7os-e-caracteres-especiais) o problema já foi resolvido, a pergunta é diferente, porém o problema e a resposta são os mesmos

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Eu não gosto de utilizar arquivos que contenham caracteres especiais, então eu sempre dou uma "limpada" nos nomes e etc.

```
  function clearId($id){
     $LetraProibi = Array(" ",",",".","'","\"","&","|","!","#","$","¨","*","(",")","`","´","<",">",";","=","+","§","{","}","[","]","^","~","?","%");
     $special = Array('Á','È','ô','Ç','á','è','Ò','ç','Â','Ë','ò','â','ë','Ø','Ñ','À','Ð','ø','ñ','à','ð','Õ','Å','õ','Ý','å','Í','Ö','ý','Ã','í','ö','ã',
        'Î','Ä','î','Ú','ä','Ì','ú','Æ','ì','Û','æ','Ï','û','ï','Ù','®','É','ù','©','é','Ó','Ü','Þ','Ê','ó','ü','þ','ê','Ô','ß','‘','’','‚','“','”','„');
     $clearspc = Array('a','e','o','c','a','e','o','c','a','e','o','a','e','o','n','a','d','o','n','a','o','o','a','o','y','a','i','o','y','a','i','o','a',
        'i','a','i','u','a','i','u','a','i','u','a','i','u','i','u','','e','u','c','e','o','u','p','e','o','u','b','e','o','b','','','','','','');
     $newId = str_replace($special, $clearspc, $id);
     $newId = str_replace($LetraProibi, "", trim($newId));
     return strtolower($newId);
  }
```

**USO**

```
$target_path = $destination_path . basename( clearId($_FILES['myfile']['name']));
```

PS.: Dependendo da códificação dos seus arquivos pode ser que seja necessário usar assim `clearId(utf8_encode($_FILES['myfile']['name']))`

Comment: Como implantar algum exemplo de como usar o código acima?

Comment: utilizando essa função `clearId()` basta trocar de: `$target_path = $destination_path . basename( $_FILES['myfile']['name'] );` para: `$target_path = $destination_path . clearId( basename( $_FILES['myfile']['name']) );`

Comment: Adicionado o uso...

Comment: Resolvido era isso mesmo com alguns ajustes na linha $LetraProibi = Array deu tudo certo obrigada

Comment: De nada, se isso resolveu marque a resposta como aceita, para que seja fechada a pergunta.

Comment: excelente resposta!

Answer (score 16):

Remover acentos de forma simples:

```
$file = "ação-íaaa.jpg";
$file = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $file);
echo "{$file} <br>";
```

Output: `acao-iaaa.jpg`

Exemplo disponível no [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/mSMV7t)

Comment: +1, mas é bom lembrar que não basta por 'UTF-8' no iconv, mas sim verificar o encoding nos headers da requisição. O browser pode estar mandando em ISO os nomes, por exemplo.

Comment: @Bacco, o estranho é que atualizei o PHP para 5.4.28 e está escapando *ac~ao-'iaaa.jpg*, não sei se é bug da versão ou alguma config antiga no ini que esqueci de alterar.

Comment: Mas no ideone o output é correto como no php anterior que eu usava, somente agora que está separando. Funcionava certinho, estou procurando algum report de bug.

Comment: Achei a resposta: "Note that the iconv function on some systems may not work as you expect. In such case, it'd be a good idea to install the » GNU libiconv library. " http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.iconv.php - O sintoma da iconv da glibc é exatamente esse que vc descreveu, separar os acentos em vez de remover.

Comment: Valeu @Bacco, vou dar uma olhada com calma. Acha que devo remover a resposta, já que não produz o efeito esperado?

Comment: A resposta está certa, só precisa por ou atualizar a libiconv no seu server para que o PHP use a libiconv no lugar da iconv glibc. Veja no `phpinfo()` na seção "iconv" qual está sendo usada.

Comment: @Bacco, beleza, depois vou instalar pra ver.

Answer (score 8):

Eu uso o código do plugin [Germanix](https://github.com/toscho/Germanix-WordPress-Plugin), de um dos moderadores do WordPress Developers e que sabe *muito* de codificação de caracteres e [Internacionalização e Localização](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internacionaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_(software)). Primeiro, ele faz um [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.html-entity-decode.php), depois converte para minúsculas, depois remove duplicatas (p.ex, `++` para `+`) de caracteres permitidos (`-=+.`) e finalmente faz o replace de caracteres não permitidos baseado numa lista bem extensa e completa.

```
/**
 * Limpar nome de arquivo no upload
 * 
 * Sanitization test done with the filename:
 * ÄäÆæÀàÁáÂâÃãÅåªₐāĆćÇçÐđÈèÉéÊêËëₑƒğĞÌìÍíÎîÏïīıÑñⁿÒòÓóÔôÕõØøₒÖöŒœßŠšşŞ™ÙùÚúÛûÜüÝýÿŽž¢€‰№$℃°C℉°F⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉±×₊₌⁼⁻₋–—‑․‥…‧.png
 * @author toscho
 * @url    https://github.com/toscho/Germanix-WordPress-Plugin
 */
function t5f_sanitize_filename( $filename )
{

    $filename    = html_entity_decode( $filename, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8' );
    $filename    = t5f_translit( $filename );
    $filename    = t5f_lower_ascii( $filename );
    $filename    = t5f_remove_doubles( $filename );
    return $filename;
}

/**
 * Converte maiúsculas em minúsculas e remove o resto.
 * https://github.com/toscho/Germanix-WordPress-Plugin
 *
 * @uses   apply_filters( 'germanix_lower_ascii_regex' )
 * @param  string $str Input string
 * @return string
 */
function t5f_lower_ascii( $str )
{
    $str     = strtolower( $str );
    $regex   = array(
        'pattern'        => '~([^a-z\d_.-])~'
        , 'replacement'  => ''
    );
    // Leave underscores, otherwise the taxonomy tag cloud in the
    // backend won’t work anymore.
    return preg_replace( $regex['pattern'], $regex['replacement'], $str );
}


/**
 * Reduz meta caracteres (-=+.) repetidos para apenas um.
 * https://github.com/toscho/Germanix-WordPress-Plugin
 *
 * @param  string $str Input string
 * @return string
 */
function t5f_remove_doubles( $str )
{
    $regex = array(
        'pattern'        => '~([=+.-])\\1+~'
        , 'replacement'  => "\\1"
    );
    return preg_replace( $regex['pattern'], $regex['replacement'], $str );
}


/**
 * Substitui caracteres não-ASCII.
 * https://github.com/toscho/Germanix-WordPress-Plugin
 *
 * Modified version of Heiko Rabe’s code.
 *
 * @author Heiko Rabe http://code-styling.de
 * @link   http://www.code-styling.de/?p=574
 * @param  string $str
 * @return string
 */
function t5f_translit( $str )
{
    $utf8 = array(
        'Ä'  => 'Ae'
        , 'ä'    => 'ae'
        , 'Æ'    => 'Ae'
        , 'æ'    => 'ae'
        , 'À'    => 'A'
        , 'à'    => 'a'
        , 'Á'    => 'A'
        , 'á'    => 'a'
        , 'Â'    => 'A'
        , 'â'    => 'a'
        , 'Ã'    => 'A'
        , 'ã'    => 'a'
        , 'Å'    => 'A'
        , 'å'    => 'a'
        , 'ª'    => 'a'
        , 'ₐ'    => 'a'
        , 'ā'    => 'a'
        , 'Ć'    => 'C'
        , 'ć'    => 'c'
        , 'Ç'    => 'C'
        , 'ç'    => 'c'
        , 'Ð'    => 'D'
        , 'đ'    => 'd'
        , 'È'    => 'E'
        , 'è'    => 'e'
        , 'É'    => 'E'
        , 'é'    => 'e'
        , 'Ê'    => 'E'
        , 'ê'    => 'e'
        , 'Ë'    => 'E'
        , 'ë'    => 'e'
        , 'ₑ'    => 'e'
        , 'ƒ'    => 'f'
        , 'ğ'    => 'g'
        , 'Ğ'    => 'G'
        , 'Ì'    => 'I'
        , 'ì'    => 'i'
        , 'Í'    => 'I'
        , 'í'    => 'i'
        , 'Î'    => 'I'
        , 'î'    => 'i'
        , 'Ï'    => 'Ii'
        , 'ï'    => 'ii'
        , 'ī'    => 'i'
        , 'ı'    => 'i'
        , 'I'    => 'I' // turkish, correct?
        , 'Ñ'    => 'N'
        , 'ñ'    => 'n'
        , 'ⁿ'    => 'n'
        , 'Ò'    => 'O'
        , 'ò'    => 'o'
        , 'Ó'    => 'O'
        , 'ó'    => 'o'
        , 'Ô'    => 'O'
        , 'ô'    => 'o'
        , 'Õ'    => 'O'
        , 'õ'    => 'o'
        , 'Ø'    => 'O'
        , 'ø'    => 'o'
        , 'ₒ'    => 'o'
        , 'Ö'    => 'Oe'
        , 'ö'    => 'oe'
        , 'Œ'    => 'Oe'
        , 'œ'    => 'oe'
        , 'ß'    => 'ss'
        , 'Š'    => 'S'
        , 'š'    => 's'
        , 'ş'    => 's'
        , 'Ş'    => 'S'
        , '™'    => 'TM'
        , 'Ù'    => 'U'
        , 'ù'    => 'u'
        , 'Ú'    => 'U'
        , 'ú'    => 'u'
        , 'Û'    => 'U'
        , 'û'    => 'u'
        , 'Ü'    => 'Ue'
        , 'ü'    => 'ue'
        , 'Ý'    => 'Y'
        , 'ý'    => 'y'
        , 'ÿ'    => 'y'
        , 'Ž'    => 'Z'
        , 'ž'    => 'z'
        // misc
        , '¢'    => 'Cent'
        , '€'    => 'Euro'
        , '‰'    => 'promille'
        , '№'    => 'Nr'
        , '$'    => 'Dollar'
        , '℃'    => 'Grad Celsius'
        , '°C' => 'Grad Celsius'
        , '℉'    => 'Grad Fahrenheit'
        , '°F' => 'Grad Fahrenheit'
        // Superscripts
        , '⁰'    => '0'
        , '¹'    => '1'
        , '²'    => '2'
        , '³'    => '3'
        , '⁴'    => '4'
        , '⁵'    => '5'
        , '⁶'    => '6'
        , '⁷'    => '7'
        , '⁸'    => '8'
        , '⁹'    => '9'
        // Subscripts
        , '₀'    => '0'
        , '₁'    => '1'
        , '₂'    => '2'
        , '₃'    => '3'
        , '₄'    => '4'
        , '₅'    => '5'
        , '₆'    => '6'
        , '₇'    => '7'
        , '₈'    => '8'
        , '₉'    => '9'
        // Operators, punctuation
        , '±'    => 'plusminus'
        , '×'    => 'x'
        , '₊'    => 'plus'
        , '₌'    => '='
        , '⁼'    => '='
        , '⁻'    => '-' // sup minus
        , '₋'    => '-' // sub minus
        , '–'    => '-' // ndash
        , '—'    => '-' // mdash
        , '‑'    => '-' // non breaking hyphen
        , '․'    => '.' // one dot leader
        , '‥'    => '..'  // two dot leader
        , '…'    => '...'  // ellipsis
        , '‧'    => '.' // hyphenation point
        , ' '    => '-'   // nobreak space
        , ' '    => '-'   // normal space
    );

    $str = strtr( $str, $utf8 );
    return trim( $str, '-' );
}
```

Aí, é só passar o nome do arquivo para a função principal:

```
t5f_sanitize_filename( $nome_do_arquivo );
```

Answer (score 7):

Coloca no inicio do script

```
ini_set("default_charset","UTF-8");
```

ou usa

```
$nome = utf8_encode($_FILES['myfile']['name']);
```

Deve resolver, pelo menos o nome fica direito, mas não remove a acentuação. Se quiser ficar com um nome único para o arquivo sem acentuação pode fazer assim:

```
$nome = md5(date("YmdHis").$_FILES['myfile']['name']).jpg;
```

Comment: Troquei   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> por <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /> na página e o nome ficou normal agora gostaria de remover os acentos

Comment: Para remover os acentos tem que usar a função do @KaduAmaral. Mas lembre-se sempre que depois quem for procurar o arquivo pelo nome original não irá o encontrar. Também pode fazer com md5(). Veja a edição.

Answer (score 3):

[Nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/858/refatora%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-remover-pontua%C3%A7%C3%A3o-espa%C3%A7os-e-caracteres-especiais), a alternativa abaixo foi a mais eficiente, Acredito que o caso seja bem semelhante.

```
function replaceChar($str){
        $str = preg_replace('/[áàãâä]/ui', 'a', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[éèêë]/ui', 'e', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[íìîï]/ui', 'i', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[óòõôö]/ui', 'o', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[úùûü]/ui', 'u', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[ç]/ui', 'c', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', '_', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/_+/', '_', $str);
        return $str;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Complementando as respostas existentes.

Existe um bloco de caracteres Unicode chamado [Combining Diacritical Marks (sinais diacríticos de combinação)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character#Unicode_ranges), eles são usados para produzir acentos.

Se o texto contiver algum desses caracteres que nenhuma das soluções apresentadas remove esses acentos. Existem duas maneiras de lidar com esse problema:

1 - remover os caracteres utilizando expressão regular:

```
<?php
// remove somente caracteres dentro do intervalo
preg_replace('/[\x{0300}-\x{036f}]+/u', '', $string);
// remove todos os caracteres do bloco de caracteres
preg_replace('/[\p{M}]+/u', '', $string);
```

2 - converter os sinais de combinação em caracteres acentuados **antes** de aplicar a remoção de acentos:

```
<?php
normalizer_normalize($string);
```

Essa função só funciona se a extensão de internacionalização "intl" estiver habilitada no servidor.

Answer (score 2):

```
function removeAcentos($string, $slug = false) {
if(mb_detect_encoding($string.'x', 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1') == 'UTF-8'){
$string = utf8_decode(strtolower($string)); }
$ascii['a'] = range(224, 230);
$ascii['e'] = range(232, 235);
$ascii['i'] = range(236, 239);
$ascii['o'] = array_merge(range(242, 246), array(240, 248));
$ascii['u'] = range(249, 252);
$ascii['b'] = array(223);
$ascii['c'] = array(231);
$ascii['d'] = array(208);
$ascii['n'] = array(241);
$ascii['y'] = array(253, 255);
foreach ($ascii as $key=>$item) {
$acentos = '';
foreach ($item as $codigo) $acentos .= chr($codigo);
$troca[$key] = '/['.$acentos.']/i'; }
$string = preg_replace(array_values($troca), array_keys($troca), $string);  if ($slug) {
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', $slug, $string);
$string = preg_replace('/' . $slug . '{2,}/i', $slug, $string);
$string = trim($string, $slug); }
return $string; }
echo removeAcentos("Palavras com acentuação");
echo removeAcentos("Palavras com acentuação", "_");
```

Answer (score 2):

A forma mais simples e eficiente de remover acentos, é mapeando os caracteres com função interna do PHP, o [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php):

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'pt_BR'); // global (pode ser LC_ALL) 

function unaccent($str){
    return iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
}
```

O [*iconv* é uma função padronizada e bem madura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv), com alto desempenho e alta confiabilidade, em geral uma chamada de função de biblioteca comum sistema operacional (Linux, Windows e demais sistemas).

Answer (score 2):

A solução abaixo também resolve o problema, e de maneira mais limpa:

```
$string = 'ÁÍÓÚÉÄÏÖÜËÀÌÒÙÈÃÕÂÎÔÛÊáíóúéäïöüëàìòùèãõâîôûêÇç'; // Entrada
$semAcentos = preg_replace('/[`^~\'"]/', null, iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string));
echo $semAcentos;

// Saída: AIOUEAIOUEAIOUEAOAIOUEaioueaioueaioueaoaioueCc
```

Agradecimentos para Carlos Coelho, de quem obtive esta solução.

Answer (score 1):

Segue função para  remover acentos utilizando expressão regular, bem mais simples e compacta.

```
<?php
function removerAcentos( $string ) {
    $mapaAcentosHex  = array(
        'a'=> '/[\xE0-\xE6]/',
        'A'=> '/[\xE0-\xE6]/',
        'e'=> '/[\xE8-\xEB]/',
        'E'=> '/[\xE8-\xEB]/',
        'i'=> '/[\xEC-\xEF]/',
        'I'=> '/[\xEC-\xEF]/',
        'o'=> '/[\xF2-\xF6]/',
        'O'=> '/[\xF2-\xF6]/',
        'u'=> '/[\xF9-\xFC]/',
        'U'=> '/[\xF9-\xFC]/',
        'c'=> '/\xE7/',
        'C'=> '/\xE7/',
        'n'=> '/\xF1/',
        'N'=> '/\xF1/'
    );
    foreach ($mapaAcentosHex as $letra => $expressaoRegular) {
        $string = preg_replace( $expressaoRegular, $letra, $string);
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mesmo existindo várias respostas, deixo aqui uma forma nova que aprendi e achei muito bacana.

```
function remover_acentos($str) {
    return preg_replace("/&([a-z])[a-z]+;/i", "$1", htmlentities($str))
}

echo remover_acentos("ação-íaaa.jpg");
```

Answer (score -1):

Uma forma mais simples:

```
function retirarAcentos($pTxt){
    $pTxt = str_replace('ç','c',$pTxt);
    $pTxt = str_replace('ã','a',$pTxt);
    return $pTxt;
}
```

O exemplo só está substituíndo "ç" por "c" e "ã" por "a", mas basta repetir essas linhas com todos os outros acentos que quiser substituir.

Answer (score -1):

This can solve your problem, i has problem when i pass the archive with accent into name and i solved verifying the size of archive and clear input if has something different than normal.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="file" placeholder="hello world" id="input_file" />

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-3zlB5s2uwoUzrXK3BT7AX3FyvojsraNFxCc2vC/7pNI="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script>
      $("input:file").change(function () {
        var fileInput = $(this); // => Gets the file data
        var fileSize = fileInput.get(0).files[0].size; // => Value in bytes
        if (fileSize == 0) {
          $("#input_file").val("");
          console.log('Something wrong :/');
        } else {
            console.log('good thats working :D');
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```