# Problema inserir nome de arquivo no banco de dados

Tags: sql, codeigniter, acentuação

Estou fazendo o upload de arquivos com o plupload usando codeigniter. Meu problema está sendo quando há caracteres especiais no nome do arquivo. Sendo que eu tenho que gravar esse nome original.

Quando há por exemplo: 'cópia' fica salvo no banco: 'co?pia'

em todo lugar da aplicação eu declaro que estou usando utf-8

Alguma sugestao?

Comment: Qual o encode do seu banco de dados?

Answer (score -1):

Tente reescrever a variável ou função que pega o nome do arquivo usando essa forma de reescrita

```
<?
/*
* Script para remover acentos e caracteres especiais:
*/

$palavra = "açúcar união";

$palavra = ereg_replace("[^a-zA-Z0-9_]", "", strtr($palavra, "áàãâéêíóôõúüçÁÀÃÂÉÊÍÓÔÕÚÜÇ ", "aaaaeeiooouucAAAAEEIOOOUUC_"));

echo($palavra);   // imprime "acucar_uniao"

/*
* A função "strtr" substitui os caracteres acentuados pelos não acentuados.
* A função "ereg_replace" utiliza uma expressão regular que remove todos os caracteres que não são letras, números e são diferentes de "_" (underscore).
*/
?>
```

Comment: Sua resposta não atende o que é pedido na pergunta. Veja que ele precisa salvar o nome original, ele não quer remover os acentos.

Comment: Sim não tinha percebido! Mais talvez esse tópico ajude http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33029/como-remover-acento-no-upload-com-php