# "Robo-Humano" Inteligente

Tags: php

Estou fazendo um "humanozinho" que você manda mensagem, e ele te responde.

Exemplo: Se você manda *"Oi"*  ele te responde  *"Olá, tudo bem?"*.

Sei que isso é básico, pode usar um `switch`.

```
switch($mensagem){
case "Oi":
    $responder  = "Ola";
    break;
case "xau":
    $responder = "Xau!";
    break;
}
```

Mas eu gostaria de identificar automaticamente o que ele digitar.

**Exemplo**: Se eu escrever uma frase *"Olá, qual seu nome"*, ele identificaria *"nome"* e *"olá"* na frase e responderia *"Olá, meu nome é João prazer!"*

O que devo estudar e aprender para fazer um protótipo deste nível?

Comment: Que tal?  https://www.wired.com/2014/04/out-in-the-open-jasper/

Comment: Uma solução mais simples é usar o método explode, se eu tiver tempo vou te mostrar um exemplo simples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja se isso te atende:

```
<form acton="#" method="post">
    <input name="speak" />
    <button>Go!</button>
</form>
<?php

 function clearId($id){
     $special = Array('Á','È','ô','Ç','á','è','Ò','ç','Â','Ë','ò','â','ë','Ø','Ñ','À','Ð','ø','ñ','à','ð','Õ','Å','õ','Ý','å','Í','Ö','ý','Ã','í','ö','ã',
        'Î','Ä','î','Ú','ä','Ì','ú','Æ','ì','Û','æ','Ï','û','ï','Ù','®','É','ù','©','é','Ó','Ü','Þ','Ê','ó','ü','þ','ê','Ô','ß','‘','’','‚','“','”','„');
     $clearspc = Array('a','e','o','c','a','e','o','c','a','e','o','a','e','o','n','a','d','o','n','a','o','o','a','o','y','a','i','o','y','a','i','o','a',
        'i','a','i','u','a','i','u','a','i','u','a','i','u','i','u','','e','u','c','e','o','u','p','e','o','u','b','e','o','b','','','','','','');
     $newId = str_replace($special, $clearspc, $id);

     return strtolower($newId);
}

function comparaComArray($array, $input) {
    foreach($array as $value)
        if(in_array($value, $input))
            return true;
    return false;
}

if(count($_POST) > 0) {
    $words = strtolower(clearId($_POST['speak']));
    $words = explode(' ', $words);

    $saudacoes = array('oi', 'ola', 'ei', 'hello');

    if(comparaComArray($saudacoes, $words) and !in_array('nome', $words))
        echo "Oi. <br>";
    else if(comparaComArray($saudacoes, $words) and in_array('nome', $words))
        echo "Oi, meu nome e jose, prazer. <br>";
    else if(in_array('tchau', $words))
        echo "Bye Bye. <br>";
    else if(in_array('seu', $words) and in_array('pai', $words) and in_array('?', $words))
        echo "Meu pai é o Antonio. <br>";
    else if(in_array('quantos', $words) and in_array('anos', $words) and in_array('voce', $words))
        echo "Ops, acabei de nascer, então tenho nenhum ano de idade<br>";
}

?>
```

Basicamente, o fluxo do código é coletar um campo de texto do formulário, retirar a acentuação dele separar ele em cada espaçamento (para ficar mais fácil comparar) e no final ir comparando se o `array` de palavras entradas tem tais palavras, de acordo com isso você dá a resposta, eu havia pensado essa coisa do `array`, pois quando estava fazendo vi que o usuário pode digitar oi ou olá ou outros, então implementei uma função que apenas recebe dois `arrays`, um com o dicionario do sistema e outro com a entrada do usuário, então ele percorre o dicionario ate encontrar uma palavra que contenha na entrada do usuário.

**Exemplo de entradas e saídas:**

Entrada: Olá

Saída: Oi.

---

Entrada: Olá qual é o seu nome ?

Saída: Oi, meu nome e jose, prazer.

---

Entrada: Quantos anos vocÊ tem ?

Saída: Ops, acabei de nascer, então tenho nenhum ano de idade

---

Entrada: Quem é o seu pai ?

Saída: Meu pai é o Antonio.

---

Entrada: Tchau josé

Saída: Bye Bye

---

Qualquer dúvida só comentar.

Fonte do tira acento: [Como remover acento no upload com php?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33029/como-remover-acento-no-upload-com-php)

Comment: @Ivcs ótima resposta era isso mesmo que eu gostaria e não vamos deixar de lado a resposta do Miguel que me ajudou a entender também e iriei utilizar as duas para projetos separados obrigado pessoal!

Answer (score 3):

Podes fazer assim:

```
$frase = 'Olá, qual seu nome?';

$ola = stripos($frase, 'olá') !== false; // cada uma destas vai ser true ou false
$nome = stripos($frase, 'nome') !== false;
$adeus = stripos($frase, 'adeus') !== false;

switch(true) {
    case($ola && $nome):
        echo 'Olá, meu nome é João prazer!';
        break;
    case($ola):
        echo 'Olá para ti também';
        break;
    case($adeus):
        echo 'Xau';
        break;
    default:
        echo 'Não queres falar comigo?';
}
```

Com `array`:

```
$frase = 'Olá qual seu nome';
$palavras = explode(' ', $frase);

switch(true) {
    case(in_array('Olá', $palavras) && in_array('nome', $palavras)):
        echo 'Olá, meu nome é João prazer!';
        break;
    case(in_array('Olá', $palavras)):
        echo 'Olá para ti também';
        break;
    case(in_array('adeus', $palavras)):
        echo 'Xau';
        break;
    default:
        echo 'Não queres falar comigo?';
}
```

Mesmo assim prefiro a primeira, que podes logo definir as palavras/frases que pretentdes fazer *match*

Comment: uma ótima resposta e funcional. Uma dúvida eu posso colocar um array ao invés de *olá* ?

$array = array('oi','ola','hello'); 
Exemplo. $ola = stripos($frase, '$array') !== false

Comment: Vou colocar uma resposta com array, mesmo resultado final @LucasBicalleto

Comment: Beleza @Miguel.

Comment: Haha @Miguel realmente a 1 seria melhor porem desta segunda forma que passou vou utilizar no meu trabalho para um projeto que tenho que fazer. Obrigado pela ótima resposta

Comment: Com `stripos` poderia dar resultado alterado, por que uma entrada por exemplo como 'Estou em Olária', entraria no `case` do olá.

Comment: Sim @Ivics é verdade, obagdo por ter chamado a atenção para isso