# Tirar acentuação de uma string

Tags: php, string

Estou a receber uma *string* por POST, e quero tirar acentuação e adicionar '_'se tiver espaço em branco. Utilizei o `strtr` mas não me funciona.

```
if (isset($_POST['txtnome'])) 
{
    $txtnome= htmlentities($_POST['txtnome']);
}

$aa = strtr($txtnome,'ÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ','AAAAAACEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiioooooouuuuyy');

echo $aa;
```

Comment: Essas crases no código são erros de digitação.

Comment: erros de digitação, como assim?

Comment: Veja a edição que eu fiz. seu código está assim na sua maquina?

Comment: Relacionadas:  http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/858/refatora%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-remover-pontua%C3%A7%C3%A3o-espa%C3%A7os-e-caracteres-especiais, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33029/como-remover-acento-no-upload-com-php.

Comment: **Nota:** realmente as perguntas que indiquei resolvem o mesmo problema (remover acentuação), porém só aqui temos respostas que corrigem esse código específico. Então optei por manter esta aberta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (isset($_POST['txtnome'])) 
{
    $txtnome = $_POST['txtnome']; // COM O htmlentities ELE CONVERTE ACENTOS EM CODIGOS HTML, sem ele o str_replace funcionará. TESTADO EM UM SCRIPT MEU. BY AKSG.
}
 //$txtnome = 'á é í oo â ã'; exemplo retorna a_e_i_oo_a_a
 $txtnome = str_replace( array(' ', 'à','á','â','ã','ä', 'ç', 'è','é','ê','ë', 'ì','í','î','ï', 'ñ', 'ò','ó','ô','õ','ö', 'ù','ú','û','ü', 'ý','ÿ', 'À','Á','Â','Ã','Ä', 'Ç', 'È','É','Ê','Ë', 'Ì','Í','Î','Ï', 'Ñ', 'Ò','Ó','Ô','Õ','Ö', 'Ù','Ú','Û','Ü', 'Ý'), array('_', 'a','a','a','a','a', 'c', 'e','e','e','e', 'i','i','i','i', 'n', 'o','o','o','o','o', 'u','u','u','u', 'y','y', 'A','A','A','A','A', 'C', 'E','E','E','E', 'I','I','I','I', 'N', 'O','O','O','O','O', 'U','U','U','U', 'Y'), $txtnome); 

echo $txtnome;
```

Comment: Pode ser somente um erro de digitação ao colar na pergunta o código... e em nenhum momento ele que substituir espaços por `_` (`str_replace`)

Comment: Fiz um teste com este código e ele não funciona: http://ideone.com/0L48Ht

Comment: Continua imprimindo com os assentos, mas a partes dos espaços funciona.

Comment: Alterei o código @akm

Comment: O problema é que sempre que se escrevo a string na pagina em codigo, por exemplo $txtnome=éé, os varios exemplos funcionam, mas como recebo por POST, imprime sempre com a acentuação.

Comment: Você aceitou a minha resposta por estar mais próximo do que você queria ou que realmente funcionou para você? @akm

Comment: O que acontece é o que recebo(txtnome) é uma input text noutra pagina, e penso que nao é uma string. A parte da acentuação não altera, mas dos espaços funciona. Se colocar a variavel com aspas, por exemplo txtnome="éé" funciona.

Answer (score 4):

Você precisa decodificar antes:

```
if (isset($_POST['txtnome'])) 
{
    $txtnome= htmlentities($_POST['txtnome']);
}

$aa = strtr(utf8_decode($txtnome), utf8_decode(' àáâãäçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöùúûüýÿÀÁÂÃÄÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝ'), '_aaaaaceeeeiiiinooooouuuuyyAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOUUUUY');

echo $aa;
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/54BgrZ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/dxffibrt-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/String/Accent.php).

Comment: Alguém poderia dizer o que está errado para dar um -1?

Comment: Acho que alguém não gostou, é bem comum por aqui (apesar de não ser um motivo válido). ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

Também é possível fazer isso com [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), o primeiro argumento use um array com caracteres acentuados e o segundo com os caracteres a serem substituidos.

```
$acentos = array('À', 'Á','Â','Ã','Ä','Å','Ç','È','É','Ê','Ë','Ì',
'Í','Î','Ï','Ò','Ó','Ô','Õ','Ö','Ù','Ú','Û','Ü','Ý','à','á','â','ã','ä','å','ç','è'
,'é','ê','ë','ì','í','î','ï','ð','ò','ó','ô','õ','ö','ù','ú','û','ü','ý','ÿ', ' ');

$sem_acentos = array('A','A','A','A','A','A','C','E','E','E','E','I','I','I',
'I','O','O','O','O','O','U','U','U','U','Y','a','a','a','a','a','a','c','e','e','e'
,'e','i','i','i','i','o','o','o','o','o','o','u','u','u','u','y','y', '_');

$txtnome = 'AçÃO í è';

echo 'string original: '. $txtnome;

$txtnome = str_replace($acentos, $sem_acentos, $txtnome);

echo '<br> string: sem acentos'. $txtnome;
```

[**Exemplo**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/r8yn-xpb8)

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa pode ser usar o `iconv`, no caso pode usar um método assim:

```
function translitAscii($texto)
{
    $encode = mb_detect_encoding($texto, mb_detect_order(), true);
    return 'ASCII' === $encode ? $texto: iconv($encode, 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $text);
}

echo translitAscii('áéí asd asd ã è');//Saida: 'a'e'i asd asd ~a `e
```

No caso os acentos serão "traduzidos" para `'` e `~` por exemplo, então criei um outro método para trocar os espaços e caracteres desnecessários por `_`:

```
function customFormatString($texto)
{
    $texto = translitAscii($texto);

    //Remove todos diferentes de A-Za-z0-9_ (adicione mais caracteres permitidos aqui) incluindo o espaço
    $texto = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9_]/', '_', $texto);

    //Remove repetições do underline, por exemplo: a__b_c ficará a_b_c
    $texto = preg_replace('/[_]+[_]/', '_', $texto);

    //Remove _ do começo e do fim da string, por exemplo: _a_b___ ficará a_b
    return trim($texto, '_');
}

echo customFormatString('á é í ó u ç');
```