# Remover acentuação em PHP (Ã)

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
function tirarAcentos($string){
    return preg_replace(array("/(á|à|ã|â|ä)/","/(Á|À|Ã|Â|Ä)/","/(é|è|ê|ë)/","/(É|È|Ê|Ë)/","/(í|ì|î|ï)/","/(Í|Ì|Î|Ï)/","/(ó|ò|õ|ô|ö)/","/(Ó|Ò|Õ|Ô|Ö)/","/(ú|ù|û|ü)/","/(Ú|Ù|Û|Ü)/","/(ñ)/","/(Ñ)/","/(Ç)/","/(ç)/","/(Ã)/"),explode(" ","a A e E i I o O u U n N C c A"),$string);
}
```

Porém, ao tentar remover um acento do "GPA - GRUPO PÃO DE ACUCAR"
Não consigo remover o Ã, em específico, já tentei de tudo e não remove.

Como eu posso remover?

Segue a aplicação:

```
session_register("SESSION");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
include('Connect.php');
include('conf.php');
include('sec.php');

$v_conexao = new MySQL($vstr_usuario,$vstr_pass,$vstr_host,$vstr_db) or die ("Can't connect with the database");
$vint_conexao=$v_conexao->Get_Connection_ID();

$ssql = "SELECT nome FROM ang_cliente ORDER BY nome ASC";
$vint_result=$v_conexao->Open_Query($vint_conexao,$ssql);
while($v_a=$v_conexao->Fetch_Into($vint_result)){
    $nome_removido = tirarAcentos($v_a['nome']);
    echo "Nome Atual: ".$v_a['nome']."<br>";
    echo "Nome Atualizado: ".$nome_removido."<br>";
    echo "<hr>";
}
```

Comment: Veja isto http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33047/15089

Comment: Jà tentei dessa forma @Inkeliz mas não dá certo :(

Comment: Pode ser que o encode da conexão está diferente do arquivo (php)

Answer (score 2):

Através da função `iconv()`:

```
$text = "GPA - GRUPO PÃO DE ACUCAR";

setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'pt_BR'); // Defines para pt-br
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $text);
```

O que dará:

```
GPA - GRUPO PAO DE ACUCAR
```

Funciona para todo o tipo de acentos e se quiseres saber mais sobre a função, é só ver aqui no [Manual de PHP - iconv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

Comment: O resultado é o mesmo... não consigo remover o "Ã"

Comment: Isso é estranho, voltei a testar o código neste editor de PHP online e funciona!! Verifica aqui --> http://www.writephponline.com/

Comment: Eu testei tudo que foi função e nenhuma delas consegue remover o Ã, já tentei usar o str_replace também, nem ele não remove. Justamente o Ã maíusculo, o minúsculo remove normalmente

Comment: @AndréBaill deve ser algum problema com o teu PHP, porque `str_replace('Ã','A',$text);` funciona, acabei de testar.. que versão de PHP usas?

Comment: @AndréBaill Podes imprimir o `$vint_result` a seguir a esta linha `$vint_result=$v_conexao->Open_Query($vint_conexao,$ssql);` e mostrar o que dá?

Comment: PHP Version 5.2.17

Comment: E pode ser como o @rray♦ disse acima, o encode pode ser diferente

Comment: se for usando o var_dump() dá este resultado: resource(4) of type (mysql result)

Comment: E estás a trabalhar com que framework? É que pode estar em encode diferente e depois não funciona como devia :s Eu não estou familiarizada com a forma como fazes a ligação a BD, por isso não sei se será disso ou não :s

Comment: (Neste caso, não estou utilizando nenhum framework). Este sistema é antigo, na versão 5.2 do PHP, se eu alterar a função, não vai funcionar corretamente. Então, não sei como proceder agora.

Comment: Já experimentaste fazer o `str_replace` da maiúscula com acento para minúscula com acento e só depois tirar o acento? Como disseste que funcionava em minúsculas, pode ser que dê para enganar assim..

Comment: Melhor, usa `strtolower()` para pores a frase toda em minúsculas, retiras o acento com a tua função `tirarAcentos($string)` e depois passas tudo para maiúscula com `strtoupper()`.. experimenta a ver se funciona :)

Comment: Observe o retorno:

Comment: Nome Atual: GPA - GRUPO PÃO DE ACUCAR
Nome Atualizado: GPA - GRUPO PÃO DE ACUCAR
Razao Atualizado: GPA - GRUPO PAO DE ACUCAR -
Query: UPDATE ang_cliente SET nome = ' GPA - GRUPO PÃO DE ACUCAR', razao = 'GPA - GRUPO PAO DE ACUCAR -' WHERE cd_cliente = '460'

Comment: Da razão social ele removeu, e do nome não... uai!

Comment: >>>>> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/72821/3635

Comment: Muito estranho @AndréBaill ! Experimenta o que o Guilherme Nascimento colocou no link acima a ver se funciona