# Remover acentos de uma string em php

Tags: php, string

To tendo problemas com os acentos no meu código e queria remover os acentos quando fizessem a pesquisa,

**Ex:**
Pesquisa: Olá | Ola.

Ao fazer uma pesquisa de Música no site ele retornar a url assim:
search.php?q=Música

e não trás nenhum resultado, MAS quando eu pesquiso por Musica ele retorna assim:

```
search.php?q=Musica
```

com os resultados.

Como faço para tirar os acentos do código abaixo:

```
<div class="search_result">
<div class="image-container">
  <a href="' . $song[0] . '/'.str_replace(' ','-',strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', '-', $song[1]), '-'))).'.html"><img src="'. $song[2] . '"></a>
</div>
<div class="search-container">
  <div class="lead"><a href="' . $song[0] . '/'.str_replace(' ','-',strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', '-', $song[1]), '-'))).'.html">' . $song[1] . '</a></div>
  <div class="search-duration">'.$lang['search_description'].' '.$description.'</div>
  <div class="search-duration">'.$lang['search_duration'].' '. $song[4] .'</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Veja se estas respostas resolvem o que você precisa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/858/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33029/101

Comment: Não funcionou ou eu não estou conseguindo arrumar.

Comment: @feliphefelix ["Não funcionou ou eu não estou conseguindo arrumar"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49645/remover-acentos-de-uma-string-em-php?noredirect=1#comment100554_49645) é vago e não específico... dá para ser mais específico para sabermos em que parte precisa de ajuda?

Comment: Editei o post!.

Comment: @flourigh rejeitei sua edição pois você tentou alterou a pergunta, tentando respondê-la. Edições não devem acrescentar nada diferente da intenção do autor da pergunta. Caso tenha uma solução, utilize o campo de resposta.

Answer (score 39):

```
$string="olá à mim! ñ";
function tirarAcentos($string){
    return preg_replace(array("/(á|à|ã|â|ä)/","/(Á|À|Ã|Â|Ä)/","/(é|è|ê|ë)/","/(É|È|Ê|Ë)/","/(í|ì|î|ï)/","/(Í|Ì|Î|Ï)/","/(ó|ò|õ|ô|ö)/","/(Ó|Ò|Õ|Ô|Ö)/","/(ú|ù|û|ü)/","/(Ú|Ù|Û|Ü)/","/(ñ)/","/(Ñ)/"),explode(" ","a A e E i I o O u U n N"),$string);
}
echo tirarAcentos($string);
```

Comment: Mas como faço no código acima?

Comment: Seu código esta incompleto pra entender, mas faz assim no começo:
`$_GET["q"]=tirarAcentos($_GET["q"]);`

Comment: Aparentemente resolve, mas vale notar que faltam umas coisinhas... ÿ ý ý ç etc.

Comment: Remover acentos de forma simples:

    $file = "ação-íaaa.jpg";
    $file = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $file);
    echo "{$file} <br>";

Output: `acao-iaaa.jpg`

Exemplo disponível no [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/mSMV7t)