# Comparar letras sem acento com letras acentuadas

Tags: php, string

Resolvi fazer um mini jogo da forca só para não enferrujar no php, estou com problemas com palavras com acentos, exemplo: maçã. Inicialmente eu a pego de um array e separo a mesmo em um array ficando (m, a, ç, ã). No jogo tenho um teclado virtual do alfabeto sem acento, como faço para quando o usuário apertar na tecla a do teclado ele além de mostrar a letra a da segunda posição também mostrar a com acento? seria comparar um caracter com outro retirando o acento deste outro. Não postei código pois nesse caso é irrelevante, já que é só fazer com que (a == ã) seja true.

Comment: Como você esta montando esse teclado ? o ideal seria um teclado com padrão ABTN até por que algumas palavras com acentuação soam diferente

Comment: Não vejo problema nisso, o teclado que tenho é como citei, apenas o alfabeto, sem acento, como todos jogos de forca.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não existe uma função nativa que faça isso. O que eu diria para fazer é criar uma função que tira os acentos antes de comparar.
[exemplo achado aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49645/remover-acentos-de-uma-string-em-php)

```
function tirarAcentos($string){
    return preg_replace(array("/(á|à|ã|â|ä)/","/(Á|À|Ã|Â|Ä)/","/(é|è|ê|ë)/","/(É|È|Ê|Ë)/","/(í|ì|î|ï)/","/(Í|Ì|Î|Ï)/","/(ó|ò|õ|ô|ö)/","/(Ó|Ò|Õ|Ô|Ö)/","/(ú|ù|û|ü)/","/(Ú|Ù|Û|Ü)/","/(ñ)/","/(Ñ)/"),explode(" ","a A e E i I o O u U n N"),$string);
}
```

então comparar o que usuário entrou com a letra sem acento

```
(tirarAcentos('a') == tirarAcentos('ã'))
```

Comment: "Não existe uma função nativa que faça isso". Depende como você considera a `iconv()`. A propósito, falta o "Ç" na sua função.

Answer (score 3):

Pode utilizar o `iconv` para retornar a letra/palavra sem acento.

Por exemplo, usando `maçã`:

```
<?php
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'pt_BR');
    // Necessário para definir os acentos brasileiros

    $array = array('m','a','ç','ã');
    // Array base

    foreach($array as $letra){
    echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ascii//TRANSLIT', $letra);
    // Resultado: maca
    }
?>
```

Caso queira [pode testar isso aqui](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/38691ba6dd32a2ae6cdd4d2e2cd38390be3c42e2). :)

Para que possa comparar com a letra escolhida pelo usuário pode criar algo parecido com:

```
<?php
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'pt_BR');
    // Necessário para definir os acentos brasileiros

    $array = array('m','a','ç','ã');
    // Array base

    foreach($array as $letra){
        if(($_POST['letra'] == iconv('UTF-8', 'ascii//TRANSLIT', $letra)){
            // m == m, a == a, c == c, a == a
            echo "Letra certa";
        }
    }
?>
```

> O "charset" *(a primeira váriavel do `iconv`)* foi alterado de `utf8` para `UTF-8` por motivos de compatibilidades. Algumas situações o `utf8` pode apresentar erro de "`Wrong charset`", enquanto o `UTF-8`corrige isto. Vale lembrar que o correto (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3629) é o `UTF-8`. ;)

Comment: Seu link está quebrado, amigo @Inkeliz

Answer (score 0):

Como nosso amigo user1811893 respondeu, não há uma função nativa que faça isso. Porém, irei compartilhar a função que eu uso. Enquanto a função dele remove todos os acentos e espaços, a abaixo também remove os acentos, porém troca os espaços por underlines (`_`):

```
function removerAcentuacao($string){
    $string = preg_replace("/[áàâãä]/", "a", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[ÁÀÂÃÄ]/", "A", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[éèê]/", "e", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[ÉÈÊ]/", "E", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[íì]/", "i", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[ÍÌ]/", "I", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[óòôõö]/", "o", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[ÓÒÔÕÖ]/", "O", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[úùü]/", "u", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[ÚÙÜ]/", "U", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/ç/", "c", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/Ç/", "C", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[][><}{)(:;,!?*%~^`&#@]/", "", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/ /", "_", $string);
    return $string;
}
```