# Função php não consegue comparar palavras com acentos

Tags: php, if, comparação

tenho uma função que compara 2 palavras, mas ao remover os acentos, mesmo assim ele identifica como palavras diferentes:

```
function acento($str, $from, $to) {
    $keys = array();
    $values = array();
    preg_match_all('/./u', $from, $keys);
    preg_match_all('/./u', $to, $values);
    $mapping = array_combine($keys[0], $values[0]);
    return strtr($str, $mapping);
}
$from = "áàãâéêíóôõúüçÁÀÃÂÉÊÍÓÔÕÚÜÇ";
$to = "aaaaeeiooouucAAAAEEIOOOUUC";

foreach($items as $i){

    $query=acento($_POST['item'], $from, $to);
    $n = mb_strlen($_POST['item'],'utf8');
    $q=acento($i, $from, $to);
    $q=substr($q,0,$n);


    if($query==$q) {
        echo 'teste'; echo "<div style='border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;margin-bottom:3px'><button type='button' value='{$i}' class='getdemanda uk-button uk-button-text uk-button-large' style='font-size:20px'>{$i}</button></div>";
    }else{
        var_dump($q,$query);
        echo '<br/>';
    }

}
```

Quando faço um `if($q==$query)` ele dá resultado false, mesmo no var dump dando exatamente a mesma coisa para os dois.

Exemplo do `var_dump($q==$query`) com texto "cópia"

```
STRING(4) "COPI" STRING(4) "COPI"
```

Comment: Qual o conteúdo de `$_POST['item']`?

Comment: O que tem no `$items`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução desse link talvez funcione [Remover acentos de uma string em php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49645/remover-acentos-de-uma-string-em-php)

Fiz o seguinte teste

```php
function tirarAcentos($string){
    return preg_replace(array("/(á|à|ã|â|ä)/","/(Á|À|Ã|Â|Ä)/","/(é|è|ê|ë)/","/(É|È|Ê|Ë)/","/(í|ì|î|ï)/","/(Í|Ì|Î|Ï)/","/(ó|ò|õ|ô|ö)/","/(Ó|Ò|Õ|Ô|Ö)/","/(ú|ù|û|ü)/","/(Ú|Ù|Û|Ü)/","/(ñ)/","/(Ñ)/"),explode(" ","a A e E i I o O u U n N"),$string);
}

$sem = tirarAcentos("Olá mundo!");
$hello = "Ola mundo!";

var_dump($sem, $hello, $hello == $sem);
```

E o resultado foi: `string(10) "Ola mundo!" string(10) "Ola mundo!" bool(true)`

Comment: deu certo!!!, valeu

Comment: Disponha @LeandroMarzullo. Galera já tinha dado um negativo kkkk povo é osso.